# Is AWS AppSync applicable for Xamarin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am using dynamoDB in my application ,

but I need my application to work in the offline mood too ,

so I am trying to use appsync for the offline mode .

but I don't know if it is available for xamarin or not

I see in its documentation that it supports android and ios ,

but did it support Xamarin (directly or even implementing it in android and ios native first then attach it to Xamarin ? )

appsync documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/welcome.html

and if it is available is there is any tutorial or sample code for this ?

any help please ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should go through their documentation for `Xamarin` and `.Net`

In the [Setting Up the AWS Mobile SDK for .NET and Xamarin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/setup.html), they have given their own samples to refer to!!

Following are the links for each service that they provide for Xamarin

[Cognito Identity](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/CognitoIdentity)

[Cognito Sync](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/CognitoSync)

[Dynamo DB](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB)

[Mobile Analytics](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/MobileAnalytics)

[S3](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/S3)

[SNS](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/SNS)

From what I understand App sync is not a part of the available official SDK's

But if you check the GitHub issue for the same which is here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/901 and check the comment by [NeilBostrom](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/901#issuecomment-497618843) he has a way of doing it through GraphQL

Goodluck!

Feel free to get back if you have queries

Comment: Thank you so much , I will try it and tell you the results .

Comment: Sure let me know if i can help you with anything

Comment: @marianabil On the Github issue, one of the AWS guys replied to one of the comments which seems relevant you can take a look https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/901#issuecomment-535666670